# What are the weights and bias for the AND perceptron?

Tags: python, pandas, neural-network

I am implementing AND Perceptron and facing difficulty in deciding the weights and bias for the combination to match it to AND Truth table.

Here's the Code that I have written:

```
import pandas as pd

# Set weight1, weight2, and bias
weight1 = 2.0
weight2 = -1.0
bias = -1.0

# Inputs and outputs
test_inputs = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
correct_outputs = [False, False, False, True]
outputs = []

# Generate and check output
for test_input, correct_output in zip(test_inputs, correct_outputs):
    linear_combination = weight1 * test_input[0] + weight2 * test_input[1] + bias
    output = int(linear_combination >= 0)
    is_correct_string = 'Yes' if output == correct_output else 'No'
    outputs.append([test_input[0], test_input[1], linear_combination, output, is_correct_string])

# Print output
num_wrong = len([output[4] for output in outputs if output[4] == 'No'])
output_frame = pd.DataFrame(outputs, columns=['Input 1', '  Input 2', '  Linear Combination', '  Activation Output', '  Is Correct'])
if not num_wrong:
    print('Nice!  You got it all correct.\n')
else:
    print('You got {} wrong.  Keep trying!\n'.format(num_wrong))
print(output_frame.to_string(index=False))
```

I have to decide  weight1,  weight2 and bias and from the mentioned values. I am getting one output wrong when there is `1` and `0` as Input.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The equation is symmetric: the two inputs are functionally equivalent.
- Taking your weights as the variables, you have four (now three) inequalities in three (now two) variables.  Where are you stuck on solving that system?

System:

```
w = weight (same for both inputs)
b = bias

0*w + 0*w + b <= 0
1*w + 0*w + b <= 0
1*w + 1*w + b >  0
```

This leaves you with

```
w + b <= 0
2*w + b > 0
```

You should be able to characterize the possible solutions from there.

Answer (score 6):

AND Perceptron:

```
weight1 = 1.0
weight2 = 1.0
bias = -2.0
```

OR Perceptron:

```
weight1 = 1.0
weight2 = 1.0
bias = -1
```

NOT Perceptron:

```
weight1 = 1.0
weight2 = -2.0
bias = 0
```

The bias acts as an intercept to adjust the linear equation.

Answer (score 3):

Try using relu activation function and see if it solves your problem

`relu(weight1 * test_input[0] + weight2 * test_input[1] + bias)`

1, 1 and -1.5 should work.

Comment: 1, 1, -1.5 worked for me but relu activation function was not required.

Comment: int(linear_combination >= 0) is in some sense acting as a relu function. If you change it int(linear_combination > 0), it becomes a relu activation function. There are numerous solutions as Prune mentioned.

Comment: thanks @Lufy yes 1,1 and -1.5 is work with me for OR operator , what about AND operator?

Answer (score 2):

**Perceptron algorithm**

prediction = 1 if `wx+b >=0 and 0 if wx+<0`

so the inputs are `(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)`
make sure the number you will input for ***weight1, weight2 and bias*** will out put `< 0` as false and `>=0` as true

1. **for inputs (0,0)**

**weight1*0+weight2*0+-2**

1*0+1*0-2 = -2

2. **for inputs (0,1)**

1*0+1*1-2 = -1

3. **for inputs (1,0)**

1*1+1*0-2 = -1

4. **for inputs (1,1)**

1*1+1*1-2 = 0

Therefore , my weight1 =1, weight2 =1 and bias = -2. I got all the answers as correct

you can use any ***weight1,weight2 and bias*** values you want as long as the output states the AND operation. Remember you can apply to OR and other operations